# php csv file data import get same page in array

Tags: php, arrays

i have upload **csv file** and get data same page in array

my form

```
<table width="600">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<tr>
<td width="20%">Select file</td>
<td width="80%"><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Submit</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>
</tr>

</form>
</table>
```

> and my csv format is

```
price;test1;test2;test3 //title of csv file
100;1;5;4               //value of above title
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: i have upload csv above formate and i want to get uploaded csv file data in array vise

Comment: Where is your file uploading code?

Comment: above is my data i want to converted in array after submit button click

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to read csv files and convert it to an array,

```
<?php
$file = fopen("your_csv_file.csv","r");
print_r(fgetcsv($file));
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: no i have upload any csv file in form after get data in array vise

Comment: If you want to get the CSV file data, you have to read that file after uploading using the above code as it will print an array then return that as reposne.

Answer (score 0):

here you have it, this will read your file and skip all empty rows, and it will automatically convert the encode to `utf_8`

```
$csv = [];
$f = fopen($file, 'r');
$i = 0;
while ($data = fgetcsv ($f, 1000, ";")) {
    if ($i != 0) {
        if((array(null) !== $data)) {
            $data = array_map("utf8_encode", $data); //added
            $csv[$i] = $data;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
//and now to print the information you just generated
echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
//die; //this is only if you want to stop your code at this point
```